# Is there any difference between the syntax used for TypoScript constants and the syntax for "Extension Configuration"?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

For both "TypoScript constants" and "Extension Configuration" (as defined in ext_conf_template.txt) use a common syntax. They are documented here:

- [Constants](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/UsingSetting/Constants.html) (in "TypoScript Template Reference")
- [Extension Configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html) (in "TYPO3 Explained")

An example:

```
# cat=basic; type=string; label=Some title
title =
```

Line 1 describes data type, category etc. of the variable.

Alternatively, we might have something like this:

```
tx_plugins.my_plugin {
    # cat=basic; type=string; label=Some title
    title = 

}
```

Besides this rather simple example, there are some more things you can do with this.

Where TypoScript constants and Extension Configuration are stored and how they are used is completely different, but I am wondering if we just look at the syntax and the features you can use - is it the same?

e.g.

- the available datatypes (boolean, integer etc.)
- that you can't use multiline values
- that you can use environment variables
- how to access files
- how to do localization

---

The reason I ask: To streamline the documentation and also I use this in my own extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer

The syntax used for TS template constants and extension configuration is the same but there are some minor differences for the available types currently.

## Deep Analysis

### Extension Configuration

For TYPO3 CMS version 6 the extension manager and configuration was rewriten from scratch based on Extbase and using the FormEngine. Available types are:

- `int`: integer values
- `int+`: positive integer values only
- `integer`: alias for `int`
- `color`: color picker
- `wrap`: wrap, lines are separated finally by `|` for the saved value
- `offset`: offset field
- `options`: select
- `boolean`: checkbox
- `user`: user function is used for rendering
- `small`: small text field
- `string`: text field
- `input`: alias for `string`, only for backwards compatibility, many extensions depend on that
- `default`: alias for `string`, only for backwards compatibility, many extensions depend on that

Source is available here: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/ViewHelpers/Form/TypoScriptConstantsViewHelper.php#L36

### TypoScript Template Constant Editor

On the other hand the TypoScript template constant editor was never rewriten to make use of the FormEngine and has it's own implementation. Here the following types are additionally available:

- `comment`: a checkbox to switch a constant
- `files`: file selection

Source is available here: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/TypoScript/ExtendedTemplateService.php#L993

### Other Questions

- that you can't use multiline values

That's almost true for the TS constant editor but there is the `wrap` type to achieve a multiline like functionality. For the extension configuration there are the `small` and `string` types.

For the other questions I'm currently not aware of and have to investigate a little bit deeper first:

- that you can use environment variables
- how to access files
- how to do localization

Answer (score 0):

As Typoscript is a configuration it can be used in multiple ways. And TYPO3 uses it differntly. So you have to diferentiate.

Constants can be used only for frontend rendering. there they are a shortcut to use a given value in different places.
Or to easily configure something (extension) without knowledge of detailed setup. Therefore you have the Constant-Editor where you can define constants which got a special information/ comment. It's like the TCA, a help to build forms and automaticaly have some validators for data. as TS-constants only are strings which can be used in the setup you do not have real data types. it is just a configuration to have some validation in the Constant-Editor.
Aside from some recursive replacement (up to a level of 10) of constants in constants definition you have no further options to compute a value.

In Typoscript setup you have (meanwhile) stdWrap funtionality nearly everywhere.

But especially extensions don't evaluate it everywhere. so in some places you have an extension configuration in setup where you only can insert fixed strings. (like in the constants)

---

on the other hand:
how can an extension be configured (with TYPO3-tools)?

Aside from the Typoscript setup (where you can use the constants), which primarily is used for the frontend rendering (*) you have a global option to configure extensions with the extension manager.
This data is stored serialized in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`. since TYPO3 9 unserialized.
It can be accessed in frontend and backend and works globaly, while the frontend typoscript or TSconfig is dependend on the page (and user).

---

This brings us to the third part of configuration: **TSconfig**

We have page-TSconfig and user-TSconfig. In `pages`, `be_users` and `be_groups` you can define a configuration with typoscript syntax. This can be enhanced with 'global' PHP code of extensions which inject further configuration in `ext_localconf.php` and `ext_tables.php` (or the successors in `/Configuration/TCA/` and `/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/`)

---

---

(*) some extensions evaluate the frontend typoscript for configuration of backend modules or plugins-options

Comment: My question was really only about defining TypoScript contants vs. Extension Configuration. And the very similar syntax used in these. Not TSconfig, not TypoScript syntax itself. While your answer is helpful, it does not really answer this specific question.